# Python asyncio.subprocess(): How to see whether it is still running

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, python-asyncio

For a `p` of class `asyncio.subprocess.Process` object created by

```
p = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(...)
```

how can I determine, in a non-blocking way, whether the system call is still running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since asyncio `Process` doesn't have a `poll()` method, you can combine `Process.wait()` and `asyncio.wait_for()`, using a tiny timeout to allow `wait()` to check whether the process is done and set the `returncode` attribute if so.

```
async def is_running(proc):
    with contextlib.suppress(asyncio.TimeoutError):
        await asyncio.wait_for(proc.wait(), 1e-6)
    return proc.returncode is None
```

Comment: That is genius! Why would Process not implement that as a member function?

Comment: @Frank-ReneSchäfer That's a good question. `subprocess.Popen` has a `poll()` method, and `asyncio.subprocess.Process` explicitly mentions that `poll()` is missing. The omission is clearly intentional, but no rationale is offered. The only reason that comes to mind is that the authors considered the above implementation "obvious" and omitted `poll()` for the same reason _timeout_ arguments are omitted from asyncio synchronization methods.

Comment: I guess, some should talk to these authors :-)

Comment: @Frank-ReneSchäfer An issue on bugs.python.org is probably a good start. And there's also a [mailing list](https://mail.python.org/mailman3/lists/async-sig.python.org/).